# Hide buttons related to empty textareas (selecting issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm struggling with a jQuery selection: I have a table that contains these columns (more or less)

- Name (input field)
- Surname (input field)
- Note (textarea)
- Button (a button to submit the relative note)

I would like to hide all buttons whose textarea is empty (to avoid the submission). This is the table:

[image]

The DOM structure of the single row is quite simple (I think):

[image]

So, I would like to select something like "all buttons contained in a td that is a brother of a td that cointains an empty textarea"...anf anf...can I do that with a single jQuery selection or not? Thank you in advance.

Comment: instead of wasting your time on creating images you could have just created a jsfiddle.. just saying..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hide buttons onLoad with the next selector:

```
$('textarea:empty').parent().next('td').find('button').hide();
```

Or if you want to disable the buttons:

```
$('textarea:empty').parent().next('td').find('button').prop("disabled", true);
```

It would be useful to check if user has type something in the textarea while on the page, and enable or not the button:

```
 $( $('textarea') ).blur(function() {
    var button = $(this).parent().next('td').find('button');
    if($(this).val() === ''){
       button.prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
       button.prop("disabled", false);
    }
 });
```

You can check this fiddle with your table included:
http://jsfiddle.net/6B9XA/4/

Comment: Can we use .change() instead of .blur()?

Comment: Yeah, you could use change() event instead of blur(). It's more specific for form elements, so, it's a good idea. And if user don't change the textarea content, no event is fired.... much better :)

Comment: onChange happens when you exit from the textarea (as onBlur). I thought that onChange happens when the text contained in the textarea changes (to check if a textarea becomes empty "interactively")

Comment: JQuery "checks" if content has changed when user exit/blur element, and if it did change, triggers the event. That's the different between change and blur if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I solved the second issue with this: "$("textarea").bind('input', function(){})" that checks if the text in the textarea changes on each keypress

Answer (score 4):

Of course!

```
$("tr td textarea").each(function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
        $(this).closest("td").next("td").find("button").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('table textarea').change(function()
{
    var thisval=$.trim($(this).html())
    if(thisval=='')
    {
      $(this).parent().next().children('button').attr('disabled')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use it this way:

```
$("#yourtableid").find("textarea").each(function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
       $(this).closest("tr").find("button").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

`"#yourtableid"` this should be changed to your table id.

#### [Selectors optimization for performance boost.](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get only the buttons who contains an empty textarea within that row

```
$('tr button').filter(function(){ // get all buttons
   return $(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').val() == ''; // only return those that are empty
}).prop('disabled',true); // disable the buttons
```